# What is the limit of the file size for the XAP in WP7 Marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

What is the limit on the file size for the XAP file inside the WP7 Marketplace?
Also what is the maximum size XAP file that you can use before the user is required to connect to WIFI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are listed in the [Windows Phone 7 Application Certification Requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=183220) (pdf) document.

- **Section 2.5:** The OTA (over the air) installation file for the application may not exceed 20 MB. Applications in excess of that size will be downloaded via Wi-Fi or through a tethered connection to a PC running the appropriate Microsoft software.
- **Section 4.1.1:** The maximum size of the XAP package file is 225 MB.

Also,

- **Section 2.8:** If your application requires the download of a large additional data package (e.g. >50 MB) to enable the application to run as described, the application description must disclose the approximate size of the data package and that additional charges may apply depending on connectivity used to acquire data.

Comment: This is perfect. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: This information has changed. To me it's unclear what the current limits are - the upper limit of 225 MB seems to be still there but there is nothing about a OTA limit as far as I can find. The 50 MB thing is now in section 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

WP market has a game chaos ring. 445 Mb of size